# How to query the Trial Balance and the General Ledger from Twinfield using SQL

Tags: microsoft-excel, invantive-control, twinfield

I'm trying to retrieve and query the Trial Balance and the General Ledger from Twinfield with Invantive Control for Excel using Invantive SQL or an Invantive Excel formula.

How would I be able to do this?